# Яндекс api 2.1 закрыть свои балун мультимаршрута?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

есть 2 мультимаршрута на карте, по клику на один открывается свой балун, и если нажать на второй маршрут то первый балун не закрывается, как его закрыть?

Создание своего балуна брал из песочницы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У маршрута есть метод `balloon.close()`, который можно использовать в этом случае. Например, так:

```
multiRoute.getActiveRoute().balloon.close()
```

Метод можно вызывать в ответ на [событие `balloonopen`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute-docpage?from=SO#event-balloonopen) второго маршрута.

Comment: Не совсем получается, я верно делаю, после того как добавил все маршруты длбавляю вот это multiRoute.events.once('balloonopen', function (e) {
      multiRoute.getActiveRoute().balloon.close();
     });

Comment: в API слушатели событий добавляются методом add, а не once; плюс вы сейчас закрываете балун того же самого маршрута, на котором случаете событие открытия балуна - это должны быть два разных маршрута.

Comment: все понял с add, а вот что делать если у меня несколько маршрутов на одной карте, и они добавляются перебором, у меня есть данные с несколькими маршрутами которые я перебираю и добавляю через multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute как тогда добавлять событие? маршрутов может быть и 20 и 30

Comment: лучше задать отдельный вопрос, в котором привести этот пример кода.
20-30 маршрутов на одной карте - перебор, какую задачу пытаетесь так решить?

Comment: есть маршруты экскурсий по стране, вот нужно вывести все маршруты, по нажатию на маршрут открывается балун где есть ссылка ведущая на страницу этого маршрута с детальным описанием. Есть json с перечнем всех маршрутов через forEach я перебираю и добавляю сам маршрут на карту с помощью multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute то есть с каждой итерацией multiRoute это как отдельная сущность выходит(((

Comment: Если нужен пример, могу обновить в этом вопросе просто

Comment: Понятно. Как ссылаться на разные маршруты уже второй вопрос, лучше задать его отдельно с примером кода. На всё в одной куче сложнее хорошо ответить.
обратите внимание, что в API есть лимит на количество маршрутов в сутки. с такими объемами легко его превысить и попасть под автоматический бан.