# Яндекс api 2.1 как закрывать балуны маршрутов при открытии балуна другого маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Сразу скажу, вопрос перекочевал [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784899/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-api-2-1-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0/784999?noredirect=1)

Имеется карта с экскурсиями и достопримечательностями и полигоном, и есть табы по переключению которых те или иные точки показываются а так же если нажат таб с экскурсиями то показываются экскурсии(маршуруты или полиолинии так как экскурсии могут быть не по дорогам а по полям). Как при открытии балуна у маршрута закрывать остальные балуны других маршрутов, на подобии как работают метки, открыл одну другая закрылась? Маршрутов может быть очень много.

Ниже пример, функция которая строит все маршруты `createRoutes()`

```js
var ymaps,
  myPolygon,
  place;
   function init() {
    var winWidth  = $(window).width(),
     myMap   = document.getElementById("map");
    $('#map .loader').fadeOut('600');
    if (!myMap) return;

    myMap = new ymaps.Map(myMap, {
     center: [53.451296, 26.473253],
     zoom: 17
    });

    var data = {
     'points': [
      {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="link-map"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка на достопримечательность</a></div>',
       "idPlace" : '2',
       'icon': 'islands#blueDotIcon',
       "latitude": 53.451296,
       "longitude": 26.473253,
       "placeType": 'type4'
      },
      {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="link-map"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка на достопримечательность</a></div>',
       "idPlace" : '1',
       'icon': 'islands#darkOrangeDotIcon',
       "latitude": 53.461017,
       "longitude": 26.458468,
       "placeType": 'type1'
      },
      {
       "infoPoint": '<div class="link-map"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка на достопримечательность</a></div>',
       "idPlace" : '3',
       'icon': 'islands#pinkDotIcon',
       "latitude": 53.443546,
       "longitude": 26.517434,
       "placeType": 'type2'
      },{
       "infoPoint": '<div class="link-map"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка на достопримечательность</a></div>',
       "idPlace" : '4',
       'icon': 'islands#darkOrangeDotIcon',
       "latitude": 53.446723,
       "longitude": 26.455979,
       "placeType": 'type1'
      },{
       "infoPoint": '<div class="link-map"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка на достопримечательность</a></div>',
       "idPlace" : '5',
       'icon': 'islands#violetDotIcon',
       "latitude": 53.500898,
       "longitude": 26.465834,
       "placeType": 'type3'
      }
     ],
     'routs':[
      {

       "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Экскурсия по Минску - Мирский замок</a>',
       "coords": [
        [53.903311, 27.560460],
        [53.684175, 27.130098],
        [53.483093, 26.740127],
        [53.451614, 26.474540]
       ],
       "routsType": 'auto',
       "colorRouts": '#c51216',
      },
      {
       "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Экскурсия по Гродно - Мирский замок</a>',
       "coords": [
        [53.675951, 23.828641],
        [53.451092, 26.474309]
       ],
       "routsType": 'auto',
       "colorRouts": '#2ecc71'
      },
            {
       "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Экскурсия Слуцк -  Лунинец</a>',
       "coords": [
        [53.019913, 27.536110],
                [52.279932, 26.824745]
       ],
       "routsType": 'auto',
       "colorRouts": '#000'
      },
            {
       "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Экскурсия не по дорогам</a>',
       "coords": [
        [53.152694, 29.223097],
                [53.136180, 29.433897],
                [53.128089, 29.494096],
                [53.099215, 29.749114]
       ],
       "colorRouts": '#000'
      }
     ],
     'polygon':[
      [53.98069667121322,23.48281326562501],[53.92237482795139,24.44961014062501],[54.135821254965,24.845117953125],[54.13541804028234,25.071710970703137],[54.19162840307183,25.157541659179685],[54.212461131324865,25.19496383935547],[54.26062781629918,25.21041336328124],[54.30823613729199,25.512537386718705],[54.27803536826016,25.521807101074145],[54.26871709234348,25.56128921777339],[54.2259414263689,25.588068392578084],[54.22711068386561,25.550131228271436],[54.20596461616174,25.570988085571248],[54.17352958687538,25.517687228027302],[54.148470112828186,25.55716934472652],[54.128235118143074,25.65158310205075],[54.166051118848046,25.718531039062473],[54.15219851737046,25.786165621581983],[54.19120056741521,25.767797854248],[54.21793174671509,25.744881060424778],[54.2301656835428,25.785135653320282],[54.31987870156001,25.681452181640584],[54.30913955810603,25.596994784179657],[54.33854004491667,25.529016878906255],[54.91540395315579,25.789942171875012],[55.15517886144831,26.350244906250012],[55.161469275239384,26.745752718750005],[55.318405996368696,26.833643343750012],[55.324670530119576,26.39419021874999],[55.5370736564162,26.558985140625],[55.72973646187694,26.657862093749994],[55.847350332138504,27.152246859375],[55.785492749027696,27.602686312500005],[56.18580509409631,28.13003006250001],[56.04463175206447,28.338770296874998],[56.093794520842614,28.668360140624994],[55.96460788821449,28.855127718749994],[55.81643388379883,30.492090609374998],[55.13000724023947,30.95351639062501],[54.744160621519114,30.898584749999994],[54.245349306933925,31.40395584375001],[54.03246953784167,31.942285921874998],[53.798981672470966,31.788477328124994],[53.7078263187784,32.579492953125],[53.4266049736835,32.777246859375005],[53.30832601729229,32.52456131250001],[53.09062343233524,32.16201248437499],[53.222697013391894,31.425928499999998],[53.031057058889346,31.261133578125012],[52.73865098506977,31.59072342187501],[52.47781385896032,31.59072342187501],[52.10730881660713,31.82143631249999],[52.087009812867834,30.95351639062501],[51.665415760310445,30.514063265625012],[51.23984103711603,30.61294021875],[51.48743442338615,30.206446078125005],[51.5080064931913,29.64614334375],[51.370682996422914,29.305567171874998],[51.68590700064187,29.173731234375012],[51.45999047647868,28.67934646875],[51.569666712411696,28.360742953125015],[51.679077622665055,28.23989334375001],[51.5765126649207,27.855371859374998],[51.62440531759449,27.196192171875005],[51.92428338247809,25.943750765625015],[51.951445757917135,25.009912875000012],[51.86990903447688,24.350733187499994],[51.590201460894576,23.99917068750001],[51.5148617757584,23.58169021875],[51.9718066934655,23.625635531250005],[52.29631876920866,23.175196078125],[52.72531268764793,23.933252718750012],[53.19631495531227,23.867334749999994],[53.720860681632345,23.58169021875]
     ]
    };

    var PlaceMarkers = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),
     AllRoutes = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),
     myBaloon,
     colorRouts,
     balloonLayout;


    var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([
     data.polygon
    ], {
     hasHint: false,
     hasBalloon: false,

    },{
     fillColor: '#c51216',
     fillOpacity: 0.1,
     strokeWidth: 2,
     strokeColor: '#c51216',
     cursor: 'default'
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);
    myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true, zoomMargin: 10});

    function createRoutes() {
     data.routs.forEach(function(item, index){
      myBaloon = item.infoPoint;
      colorRouts = item.colorRouts;
      createBaloon(myBaloon);

      if(item.routsType === "auto"){
              multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
                {
                  referencePoints: item.coords,
                  params: {
                    results: 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  // Внешний вид путевых точек.
                  wayPointStartIconLayout: "default#image",
                  wayPointStartIconImageHref: "images/temp/icon_blue.svg",
                  wayPointStartIconImageSize: [20, 30],
                  wayPointStartIconImageOffset: [-10, -30],

                  wayPointFinishIconLayout: "default#image",
                  wayPointFinishIconImageHref: "images/temp/icon_blue.svg",
                  wayPointFinishIconImageSize: [20, 30],
                  wayPointFinishIconImageOffset: [-10, -30],
                  pinIconFillColor: colorRouts,
                  pinActiveIconFillColor: colorRouts,
                  pinVisible: false,

                  routeStrokeWidth: 3,
                  routeStrokeColor: colorRouts,
                  routeActiveStrokeWidth: 3,
                  routeActiveStrokeColor: colorRouts,

                  wayPointVisible: false,
                  wayPointStartVisible: true,
                  wayPointFinishVisible: true,
                  balloonLayout: balloonLayout,
                  balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0
                }
              );

              AllRoutes.add(multiRoute);
              myMap.geoObjects.add(AllRoutes);

              /*multiRoute.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
                 multiRoute.getActiveRoute().balloon.close(); 
              });*/
      }
      else{
       var polyline = new ymaps.Polyline(
        item.coords, {
        }, {
         balloonLayout: balloonLayout,
         balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
         strokeColor: colorRouts,
         strokeWidth: 3,
         opacity: .5
        });
       
       AllRoutes.add(polyline);
       myMap.geoObjects.add(AllRoutes);

      }
     });
    }
    function createBaloon(myBaloon){
     balloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      '<div class="my-balloon">' +
      '<div class="my-balloon__arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="my-balloon__inner">' +
      '<a class="close" href="#"><svg class="icon icon-cros">' +
      '<use xlink:href="#icon-cros"></use></svg></a>' + myBaloon +
      '</div>'+
      '</div>',
      {
       build: function () {
        this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);
        this._$element = $('.my-balloon', this.getParentElement());
        this._$element.find('.close').on('click', $.proxy(this.onCloseClick, this));
       },
       onCloseClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.events.fire('userclose');
       }
      }
     );
     return balloonLayout;
    }

    function changePlace(dataPlace) {
     data.points.forEach(function(item){
      if(item.placeType === dataPlace){
       place = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [item.latitude, item.longitude],
        {
         idPlace: ''+item.idPlace+'',
         balloonContent: item.infoPoint
        },
        {
         preset: ''+item.icon+'',
        }
       );
       PlaceMarkers.add(place);
      }
     });
     myMap.geoObjects.add(PlaceMarkers);
    }

    $('body').on('change', '.place__tab-radio', function(){
     var that = $('.place__tab-radio:checked');
     PlaceMarkers.removeAll();
     AllRoutes.removeAll();
     if(that.data('routs')){
      myMap.geoObjects.remove(PlaceMarkers);
      createRoutes();
     }
     else{
      changePlace(that.data('place-type'));
     }
    });
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
    if (ymaps != undefined) ymaps.ready(init);
   });
```

```css
#map{
height: 500px;
}

.my-balloon{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 5px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -150px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 width: 300px;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.my-balloon__inner{
 display: block;
}
.my-balloon__inner .close{
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.my-balloon__inner .icon-cros{
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  fill: $text;
}

.my-balloon__arrow{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -17px;
 margin-left: -12px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform-origin: top left;
}
.my-balloon__arrow:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="place__tabs">
  <input id="place1" class="place__tab-radio" type="radio" data-place-type="type1" name="place">
  <label for="place1">вид 1</label>
  <input id="place2" class="place__tab-radio" type="radio" data-place-type="type2"  name="place">
  <label for="place2">вид 2</label>
  <input id="place3" class="place__tab-radio" type="radio" data-place-type="type3" name="place">
  <label for="place3">вид 3</label>
  <input id="place4" class="place__tab-radio" type="radio" data-routs="true" data-place-type="type1" name="place">
  <label for="place4">экскурсии</label>
  <input id="place5" class="place__tab-radio" type="radio" data-place-type="type4" name="place">
  <label for="place3">вид 4</label>
</div>
 <div id="map"></div>
 
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute">
 <symbol id="icon-cros" viewBox="0 0 31.2 31.2"><path d="M31.2 29.7L17 15.6 31.1 1.4 29.7 0 15.6 14.2 1.4.1 0 1.5l14.2 14.1L.1 29.8l1.4 1.4L15.6 17l14.2 14.1 1.4-1.4z"></path></symbol>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет, нужно просто пробежаться по всем геообъектам и закрыть балуны у всех кроме текущего. Текущий можно получить из события (поле target):

```
var target = e.get('target');
```

Объект multiRoute состоит из нескольких маршрутов к каждому привязан балун. Так что для каждого multiRoute придется получить список его маршрутов и закрыть балун каждого маршрута:

```
var routes = multiRoute.getRoutes();
routes.each((route) => route.balloon.close());
```

Вот пример полностью:

```
var routes =[
    [
      [53.903311, 27.560460],
      [53.684175, 27.130098],
      [53.483093, 26.740127],
      [53.451614, 26.474540]
    ],
    [
      [53.675951, 23.828641],
      [53.451092, 26.474309]    
    ],
    [
      [53.019913, 27.536110],
      [52.279932, 26.824745]
    ],
    [
      [53.152694, 29.223097],
      [53.136180, 29.433897],
      [53.128089, 29.494096],
      [53.099215, 29.749114]
    ]
];

ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [53.55, 27.33],
            zoom: 6
        }, {});

     routes.forEach((route) => {
            var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
            referencePoints: route
        });

        multiRoute.events.add('balloonopen', (e) => {
          var target = e.get('target');
          myMap.geoObjects.each((multiRoute) => {
            if (multiRoute != target) {
              var routes = multiRoute.getRoutes();
              routes.each((route) => route.balloon.close()); 
            }
          });
            console.log('Open')
        });

        myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
     });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nsma2yan/22/

Comment: Спасибо мил человек, цены вам нету!!!!